# I have treeNode view Code How To convert it for Recursive Function

Tags: c#, database, treeview, nodes

I have a code well functioning and working to increase it functionality and make a code I thought using recursive function would be great I have tree view node
code when i tried to make this to recursive function it does not show it will display a empty box Here is my normal code

```
 public   string ParentNode_Query = @"Select COMPONENT_NAME 
                                               from Table 
                                               where PARENT_NAME is null";

    public  string Rest_of__Node_Query = @"Select COMPONENT_NAME 
                                               from Table
                                               where 
                                               PARENT_NAME=@Parentname";

       public Task Populate_Tree_View(TreeView treeView)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand new1 = new SqlCommand(@"select COMPONENT_NAME from bom", Connection);
            var data = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(new1);
            while (true) {
                SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Database_Query.ParentNode_Query, Connection);
                var data_Parent = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(SqlCommand);

                foreach (DataRow frist in data_Parent.Rows)
                {
                    Parent_Node = new TreeNode(frist["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                    SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Database_Query.Rest_of__Node_Query, Connection);
                    SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parentname", frist["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                    // These Variable are created  purpose are for clean and readble code
                    var data_Second_Node = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(SqlCommand);
                    foreach (DataRow second in data_Second_Node.Rows)
                    {
                        Second_Node = new TreeNode(second["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                        Parent_Node.Nodes.Add(Second_Node);
                        SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Database_Query.Rest_of__Node_Query, Connection);
                        SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parentname", second["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                        var data_Third_Node = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(SqlCommand);

                        foreach (DataRow third in data_Third_Node.Rows)
                        {
                            Third_Node = new TreeNode(third["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                            Second_Node.Nodes.Add(Third_Node);
                            SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Database_Query.Rest_of__Node_Query, Connection);
                            SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parentname", third["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                            var data_Fourth_Node = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(SqlCommand);
                            foreach (DataRow fourth in data_Fourth_Node.Rows)
                            {
                                Fourth_Node = new TreeNode(fourth["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                                Third_Node.Nodes.Add(Fourth_Node);
                                SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Database_Query.Rest_of__Node_Query, Connection);
                                SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parentname", fourth["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                                var data_Fifth_Node = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(SqlCommand);
                                foreach (DataRow five in data_Fifth_Node.Rows)
                                {
                                    Fifth_Node = new TreeNode(five["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
                                    Fourth_Node.Nodes.Add(Fifth_Node);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                treeView.Nodes.Add(Parent_Node); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask; 
    }


public class DataTableCreation
{
    private SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter;
    // use this method to Create a Datatable and fill it with data
    public DataTable dataTable_Create_Method(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
    {
        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }

}
```

As you can see the similar method is repeating all over the places to reduce this i thought recursive is good. But i tried diffrent way from internet i does not work. Another Problem is the table does not contain any Id field so I have to filter them using Component name also I need this function to use if i alter the database also. Is this possible to do in recursive is that so how to this

Comment: have you run this code?  that while (true) does not have a break anywhere so will never exit

Comment: It will be faster if you got the entire table and then did all the recursion in c#.  Right now you are doing multiple queries to the database which is much slower than doing just one query.  If you post a sample rows of the DataTable it is real easy for me to write the recursive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, but you'll need to run it and debug it.

```
public  Task Populate_Tree_View(TreeView treeView)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand new1 = new SqlCommand(@"select COMPONENT_NAME from bom", Connection);
        var data = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(new1);

        var SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Database_Query.ParentNode_Query, Connection);
        var data_Parent = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(SqlCommand);
        PopulateRows(treeView.Nodes, data_Parent); 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, MediaTypeNames.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
public static void PopulateRows(TreeNodeCollection nodesCollection, DataTable rowsData)
{
    foreach (DataRow child in rowsData.Rows)
    {
        var thisNode = new TreeNode(child["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
        nodesCollection.Add(thisNode);
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Database_Query.Rest_of__Node_Query, Connection);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parentname", child["COMPONENT_NAME"].ToString());
        var dataChildNode = Table.dataTable_Create_Method(sqlCommand);
        PopulateRows(thisNode.Nodes, dataChildNode);
    }
}
```